# flutter row widget space between doesn't work. how can i fix this?

Tags: flutter, row, space

[image]

[image]

I wanna give space between Math and A+.

I tried

1. mainAxisAlignment.spacebetween
2. insert Spacer()
3. wrap with Container() and give width : infinity

all doesn't work. don't know why
here's my code

```
 body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kFadingBackgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 2.5), //(x,y)
                      blurRadius: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70.w, vertical: 10.h),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 45.w, right: 45.w),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // SizedBox(height: 5),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/math.png'),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 30.w),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Row( ✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Math',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 100.sp, color: blueGray),
                              ),

                              // SizedBox(
                              //   width: double.infinity,
                              // ),
                              // Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'A+',
                                style: TextStyle(color: blueGray),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 300,
                          child: Text(
                            'hellowoasasasasassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssrld lroremkasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdremmws',
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ));
          },
        ),
      ),
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the second column in an Expanded widget and give the Row mainAxisSize.Max and try spacer or space between
or you can try wrapping the Text("Math") in an Expanded widget.

you can find more info on Expanded Widget [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo)